# Why the tag search is not showing any questions?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Questions appear on a search, but not when I click on a tag. Am I doing something wrong?

Search: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=i+cyanogenmod

Tag: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod

Comment: Both links return questions for me.

Comment: The first version is a text search, not a tag search.  Search `[tagname]` instead of `tagname` if you want a tag search.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I was on the 'active bounty' thing.

"There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?"

Should the URL give some clue?

Comment: Ah, so I was correct with my *initial* comment (being on the wrong tab; I removed that part unfortunately, as clicking each tab brought results for me – no "bounty" tab in tags). No, the URL only gives a clue when you just clicked on a tab. Then your last tab is remembered with your session.